# Select a check box from a list of run time generated check boxes on the basis of a text value, using Python and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<tr class="tinside">
<td style="width:80px;">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkCheck(4);" value="1151218123182|N" 
    name="cityno">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="dds_id4">
    DELHI 
</td>
```

I can select checkbox by using below command `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @onclick='checkCheck(5);']").click()`

but first we have to know the numeric value like 5 used in the command.
numeric values are assigning at run time like delhi -- 4 mumbai --5 jaipur --6 London --7 paris -- 8 Lucknow --9

I only knows the city name but values are assigned at run time and hidden ... so input parameter is city name. Thanks in advance for sharing your valuable suggestion..

UPDATE #2

```
 <html><head> 
<body>
<div id="container"><div class="align_center">
<table class="table_style">
<tbody><tr class="table_header">
<tr class="tinside">
<td style="width:80px;">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkCheck(12);" value="1151228060704|N" name="ordno">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="dds_id12"><input type="hidden" value="CANS" name="status12">DLEH</td>
<td class="center_align">ABC</td>
<input type="hidden" value="9341" id="stk_token12" name="stk_token12"><td class="center_align">XYZ</td>
<input type="hidden" value="NN" id="stk_me12" name="stk_me12"><td class="center_align">11275</td>
<td class="center_align">-</td>
<td class="center_align">0.00</td>
<td class="center_align">-</td>
<td class="center_align">Item1</td>
<td class="center_align">Price</td>
<td class="center_align">Rs. 30.40</td>
<td class="center_align">Dec 27 2015</td>
<td class="center_align">0.00</td>
<td class="center_align">0 </td>
<td class="center_align">NN</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tinside">
<td style="width:80px;">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="checkCheck(12);" value="1151228060704|N" name="ordno">
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="dds_id12"><input type="hidden" value="CANS" name="status12">DELHI</td>
<td class="center_align">ABC</td>
<input type="hidden" value="9341" id="stk_token12" name="stk_token12"><td class="center_align">XYZ</td>
<input type="hidden" value="NN" id="stk_me12" name="stk_me12"><td class="center_align">11275</td>
<td class="center_align">-</td>
<td class="center_align">0.00</td>
<td class="center_align">-</td>
<td class="center_align">Item2</td>
<td class="center_align">Price</td>
<td class="center_align">Rs.35.40</td>
<td class="center_align">Dec 27 2015</td>
<td class="center_align">0.00</td>
<td class="center_align">0</td>
<td class="center_align">NN</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div></div>
</body>
</html></head>
```

I need to get check box on the basis of checkbox name and its price like in given example, need to select checkbox name DELHI and price value Rs. 35.40. These are two parameters available to select the correct checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can uniquely identify the checkbox based on the `td` element's text content.

So, in order to identify the checkbox corresponding to '*DELHI*', we can write the same statement with modified xpath as:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'DELHI')]/input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

**Answer to revised question under 'Update #2'**

If you want to select the checkbox based on the price, we can do it using the below xpath:

```
//td[contains(., 'Rs.35.40')]/parent::tr/td[contains(.,'DELHI')]/input[@type='checkbox']
```

In this xpath, we are first identifying the cell (td) which contains the desired price (Rs.35.40), and based on it - we're identifying its parent (which is a 'tr'). Having identified the desired 'tr', we are then finding the desired checkbox which is located under the 'td' with text content 'DELHI'.

Hence, your revised code, to select the 'DELHI' checkbox corresponding to the price 'Rs.35.40' would be as below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'Rs.35.40')]/parent::tr/td[contains(.,'DELHI')]/input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks Mukesh.. its working ... need one more help... if i want to get xpath of this element .. how can i find by command line?

Comment: actually multiple delhi checkboxes could be possible.. need to add more condition...

Comment: @Randhir You can inspect your DOM elements using Firebug (a firefox add on). Also, you can evaluate the correctness of your xpath with the help of Firepath (again an add on).

Comment: @Randhir : can you provide more details (html source) regarding multiple checkboxes with same text? Your original question was to select the check box by its text and it's answered i believe. We can normally use '(xpath-expression)[n]' syntax to identify the desired instance of the element (where 'n' would be index number). HTH..

Comment: Hi Mukesh, Thanks for your proactive help.

Comment: Actually there is a row of elements, in which checkbox is the first element and there may be multiple  checkbox could have same name so i need to add one more condition with existing commad to make it unique. apart from this i need to take few more value from same selected row.. currently I am using following command but its very lengthy and complex process to reach this command (identifying the correct row)

Comment: strVal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div/form/table[2]/tbody/tr["+str(tmpCount)+"]/td[16]").text                                                                              command which you have shared to select checkbox, made my work very simple, if i will get the row number of this table.

Comment: @Randhir: It is really difficult to understand your new question based on your description in the comments. Can you append the page html as well as your new question onto your original post beneath a title like **Update #2**? This will be helpful..

Comment: @Randhir: I edited my above answer to accomplish your revised question under 'Update #2'. (Request you edit your original question, and merge the new question in the same). HTH.